# Adding "one" to an expression like "more than the average"

Tags: word-usage, sentence

Is it necessary to add the word "one" in the following sentence?

> Mary was clearly not a typical child; she was more quiet and
>   inexpressive than the average (one).

Does that *one* belong there?

Comment: Connected to the phrase but not to your question I would have thought saying: "*Mary was clearly not typical*; *she was quieter and less expressive than the/your average child*" would make the sentence sound more natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*One* here is needed.

If it just said, "she was more quiet and inexpressive than the average," it's too unclear. The average what? The average apple? The average monkey?

**ODE** *one*:

> a single person or thing

So it means "than the average person."

Comment: I agree that _one_ is needed in the O.P.'s sentence, but I don't agree with your justification. If _one_ means "a single person or thing," then "she was more quiet than the average one" could still refer to a monkey. Moreover, the word _one_ would not be needed if the article were omitted: _she was more quiet and inexpressive than average_ is just fine. The issue isn't ambiguity, it's how the expressions "than the average" and "than average" are typically used.

Comment: I disagree that *one* is needed in the O.P.'s sentence, and also disagree with the idea that it's unclear without it.  I'd leave it out (if I had to write a sentence just that way) or rephrase, perhaps like  “Mary was atypical, being more quiet and inexpressive than other children”.